# iOS Facebook share Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm using this code but when I am sharing a post, the content of dialog is sharing. But after completing, the sharing page is not dismissed automatically.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code for share and issue have been solved:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation { 
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation] || [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```